# ubuntu tomcat localhost can access website,but outside browser can not open

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I encounted a strange problem. I have installed tomcat, jdk, mysql in server. And when I run the command `w3m http://127.0.0.1:8080`, I can see the 'It works !' Page. But when I input the IP address in browser. It says `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. And even I closed the firewall in server. It also can not access the website. I don't know why it happened. Hope someone can tell me what should I do. Thank you!

Comment: Tomcat is bound to localhost. Edit the tomcat/conf/server.xml file and change the address line

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The problem is cloud server provider. The provider closed the 8080 port. When open the port, it works well.